# kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -6

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, kernel-panic, shutdown, power-management

I have a MacBook pro retina 13-inch, early 2015.

A couple of months ago I got the "service battery notification", now my MacBook is turning off randomly, sometimes repeatedly in a short period of time. It doesn't seem to make a difference if its on battery or plugged to a power source.

When I run `log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "shutdown cause"' --last 24h` 
I get both:

- `kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -6`
  and
- `kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause 0`

Cause `0` looks like it is power related and I haven't found any documentation on `-6`, but I don't know what to do to fix it. Two years ago I spilled juice in this MacBook, it was presenting all sorts of problems, but then it all stopped after I washed it with isopropyl alcohol, should I do it again?

I already reset SMC lots of times, it made no difference.